# jQuery find() select option not working in IE9

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-9

The following code works perfectly in non-IE browsers.

```
<select id="mySelect" name="mySelect">
  <option value="1">MyVal1</option>
  <option value="2">MyVal2</option>
  <option value="3">MyVal3</option>
</select>
```

I'm trying to clear out the options so I can add new ones:

```
var mySelect = $("#mySelect");
mySelect.find("option").remove();
```

It works the first time I try to populate it, but then every subsequent time thereafter, it ignores me.

Comment: Can you jsfiddle it so that we can also check it on our IE9?

Comment: [Fiddled.](http://jsfiddle.net/d9tb2/)

Comment: Works fine in my IE9 (and in IE8 compatibility mode). I can add/clear as many times as I like. (Even add consecutively.)

Comment: thanks eric sorry i thought it wasn't for tag but the fiddle...that actually works...

Comment: Why do you know that `find` doesn't work?

Comment: Why not just use [`.empty()`](http://api.jquery.com/empty) - `$('#mySelect').empty()`

Comment: Did you clear the browser cache ?

Comment: How are you subsequently populating it? Ajax? It doesn't appear to be bound to any event, so it will only be executed once.

Comment: It seems to get my ajax event that populates it, yet it's putting in the old values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For removing options from a select, use `.empty()`. Works better, cross-browser wise.

```
mySelect.empty();
```

[**jsFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/d9tb2/2/)

Comment: That empties the options, you probably want to empty the select